# How to display a plotly graph in metric or imperial units plus a minor question regarding to position 3rd y-axis

Tags: python, plotly, radio-button

I want to create using plotly a graph similar to the attached picture. My current code is working but I have not figured out two things:

1: The third y-axis should be inside the right y-axis (with labels, ticks etc- inside). For whatever reason I can't manage that. Where is the problem?

2: The provided data of the three graphs pressure, velocity and distance is in metric units. How to create using plotly's functionality a radio button which allows the user to change the result to imperial units (Psi instead of bar, fps instead of m/s, inch instead of mm). Naturally my code could easily manage the conversion. But to use plotly's functionality seems to make in my case more sense.

Please find attached my current code including a pic of the result and the desired outcome.

Thanks - Arthur
PS:
Sorry that my handwriting is not exactly the prettiest on earth.
In case any of you have a better idea to display three units in the same graph, I'd be happy to see...

[Currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dS6vY.png)

[Desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1ucH.jpg)

```
    def output_plot(self, plot_data):
        # extract from the original data
        time_data = [0.001, 0.101, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]
        velocity_data = [0, 0.1, 5.3, 19.3, 47.7]
        distance_data = [0, 0, 0, 1, 2]
        pressure_data = [26.1, 41.6, 66.1, 105.5, 168.2]
        cartridge_pmax = [3000]
          
        # Find index of maximum pressure and velocity for annotation
        max_pressure_index = pressure_data.index(max(pressure_data))
        max_velocity_index = velocity_data.index(max(velocity_data))

        # Create traces
        self.plot_output.data = [
            # Pressure
            go.Scatter(
                x=time_data,
                y=pressure_data,
                mode="lines",
                name="Pressure",
            ),
            # Velocity
            go.Scatter(
                x=time_data, y=velocity_data, mode="lines", name="Velocity", yaxis="y2"
            ),
            # Distance
            go.Scatter(
                x=time_data, y=distance_data, mode="lines", name="Distance", yaxis="y3"
            ),          
        ]


        # Create layout with synchronized axes
        self.plot_output.config['displayModeBar'] = False
        self.plot_output.layout = {
            "margin": dict(t=50, b=50),
            "legend": {
                "orientation": "h",
                "yanchor": "bottom",
                "xanchor": "center",
                "x": 0.5,
                "y": 1.05,
            },
            "xaxis": {
                "title": "Time [ms]",
                "rangemode": "tozero",
                "showgrid": False,
                "ticklen": 5,
            },
            "yaxis": {
                "title": "Pressure [bar]",
                "rangemode": "tozero",
                "showline": True,
                "showgrid": False,
                "ticklen": 5,
            },
            "yaxis2": {
                "title": "Velocity [m/s]",
                "rangemode": "tozero",
                "side": "right",
                "overlaying": "y",
                #"tickmode": "sync",
                "anchor": "x",
                "showline": True,
                "showgrid": False,
                "ticklen": 5,
            },
            "yaxis3": {
            "title": "Distance [mm]",
            "rangemode": "tozero",
            "side": "right",
            "overlaying": "y",
            "anchor": "free",
            "showline": True,
            "showgrid": False,
            "ticklen": 5,
            #"autoshift": True,
            "yaxis_title_standoff": 100,
            "ticks": "inside",
            "ticklabelposition": "inside",
            },      
            "annotations": [
                {
                    "text": "P<sub>CIP, max</sub>-20%",
                    "x": 0,
                    "y": cartridge_pmax * 0.8,
                    "showarrow": False,
                    "font": {
                        "color": "orange",
                    },
                    "xanchor": "left",
                    "yanchor": "top",
                },
                {
                    "text": f"P<sub>CIP, max</sub>= {cartridge_pmax:.0f} bar ({(cartridge_pmax*14.503773773):.0f} psi)",  # "P<sub>max</sub>",
                    "x": 0,
                    "y": cartridge_pmax,
                    "showarrow": False,
                    "font": {
                        "color": "red",
                    },
                    "xanchor": "left",
                    "yanchor": "top",
                },
                {
                    "text": f"P<sub>max</sub> = {max(pressure_data):.0f} bar",
                    "x": time_data[max_pressure_index],
                    "y": max(pressure_data),
                    "ax": 20,
                    "ay": 30,
                },
                {
                    "text": f"v<sub>max</sub> = {max(velocity_data):.0f} m/s",
                    "yref": "y2",
                    "x": time_data[max_velocity_index],
                    "y": max(velocity_data),
                    "ax": -20,
                    "ay": 30,
                },
                {
                    "text": "Watermark",
                    "textangle": -30,
                    "opacity": 0.2,
                     "font": {
                       "color": "black",
                       "size": "20"
                     },
                    "xref": "paper",
                    "yref": "paper",
                    "x": 0.5,
                    "y": 0.5,
                    "showarrow": False,
                },
            ],        
        }
```

Comment: Can you apply the data you are graphing to reproduce your data? If you have the data, I would have a better chance of getting an answer.

Comment: Sure, I added the first few data points.